# Windows SSTP VPN - connect from Mac

Tags: vpn, macos-sierra

You may know that windows server VPN often can run on SSTP. Connecting from Windows 10 is pretty easy, but if you have to work remotely from your personal Mac? Mac OS does not support SSTP VPN out of the box.

[image]

Comment: Could this be moved to askDifferent? It's a good question and helpful answer.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Below is short instruction what to do if you want to connect Windows SSTP VPN from MacOS

Prerequisites:
Homebrew installed - see [here](http://brew.sh/)

Run terminal and install sstp-client

```
brew update
brew install sstp-client
```

In order to connect to your SSTP VPN with login and password use the following command line:

```
sudo /usr/local/sbin/sstpc --log-stderr --cert-warn --user <user> --password <password> <server> usepeerdns require-mschap-v2 noauth noipdefault defaultroute refuse-eap noccp
```

If you prefer to have UI to start your VPN connection you can use iSstp

https://www.axot.org/2015/03/03/isstp-a-sstp-client-for-mac-osx/

Comment: This command line doesn't work for me. After entering my password I get `sudo: /usr/local/sbin/sstpc/sstpc: command not found`. I've asked a question that links to here: [*Connect to SSTP VPN using MAC OS X*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45273192/connect-to-sstp-vpn-using-mac-os-x).

Comment: Looks like it's only one working way to connect last version mac os to SSTP VPN. Who knows how to disconnect after that? Because after even closing console, it continues working, and the only reboot stops it.

Comment: @AntonTkachov I use iSstp as UI and it allows to connect and disconnect from statusbar.

Comment: Cannot find an option to use certificate instead of user/password. Any help with command line options for this ?

Comment: It works perfectly but when I connect to SSTP I can *only* access VPN resources. How can I fix it?

Comment: I run the command above and connect no problem then I dod a [ctrl] c and the VPN connection closed (verified both with ipchicken and saw that my IP was changes)

Comment: `require-mschap-v2` is an insecure and obsolete directive. Why would that be included?

Comment: The cli worked perfectly on MacOS Big Sur (11.1);  I didn't try the UI because the last update was in 2016...

Comment: @feedthemachine, I'm not a specialist, but you could run some commands to config the routes so the normal traffic could pass out of the VPN connection.
For example:
$ route add -net 10.0.x.0/24 -interface ppp0 (vpn traffic, defined by the subnet, is going to use this interface)
$ route change default 192.168.0.x (network traffic is going to use this gateway by default)

- You can read more here: https://gist.github.com/taldanzig/4628573

Answer (score 1):

I hade some problem with this too, so I deleted one `/sstpc` and command `sudo /usr/local/sbin/sstpc` was correct