# How to route not all the traffic over sstp-client

Tags: windows, macos, vpn, macos-catalina

I used the solution from this thread [Windows SSTP VPN - connect from Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40590806/windows-sstp-vpn-connect-from-mac), along with other dozen VPN clients on MAC.

I simply need to:

- connect to VPN

```
Port=VPN1-0
Device=WAN Miniport (SSTP)

DEVICE=vpn
PhoneNumber=vpn.company.com
...
```

- route only required traffic over this VPN channel.

I see that before connecting to VPN I have 26 routing tables and after I connect to VPN -76.

I'm able to connect to SSTP VPN using this command:
`sudo /usr/local/sbin/sstpc --log-stderr --cert-warn --user me@me.com --password super! vpn.company.com usepeerdns require-mschap-v2 noauth noipdefault defaultroute refuse-eap noccp`

However, when I'm connected to VPN I have **no Internet access**. I have only access to resources that are behind VPN.

I have a feeling that one of the parameters I pass to this command can solve my problem.
I wasn't able to isolate which one though. I also would appreciate:

- any documentation on sstp-client
- any other alternatives I can use to connect from my MAC Catalina OS to Windows VPN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `nodefaultroute` and add network to the route table manually:

`sudo route add -net "172.16.0.0/12" -interface ppp0`