# sstp vpn on Mac OS Big Sur - could not complete write of frame, could not forward packet to pppd

Tags: homebrew, frame, vpn, packet, pppd

**For the past few months I have successfully been using my Mac to connect to a Windows sstp VPN for work using homebrew....until now.**

I followed the instructions here:
[Windows SSTP VPN - connect from Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40590806/windows-sstp-vpn-connect-from-mac/40590807#40590807)

and use this command:

```
sudo /usr/local/sbin/sstpc --log-stderr --cert-warn --user <user> --password <password> <server> usepeerdns require-mschap-v2 noauth noipdefault defaultroute refuse-eap noccp
```

Now, out of nowhere, I get an error:

```
Mar 24 12:20:50 sstpc[5481]: Could not complete write of frame
Mar 24 12:20:50 sstpc[5481]: Could not forward packet to pppd
Mar 24 12:20:50 sstpc[5481]: Could not complete write of frame
Mar 24 12:20:50 sstpc[5481]: Could not forward packet to pppd
Mar 24 12:20:51 sstpc[5481]: Connection was aborted, Reason was not known
**Error: Connection was aborted, Reason was not known, (-1)
```

The numbers in the brackets sstpc[nnnn] vary, they're not always what is above.

I tried updating homebrew, reinstalling the sstp-client from homebrew, restarting my computer.

What else can I try?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is a serious bug in sstp-client 1.0.14 which causes this [1], you likely need to downgrade to 1.0.13.

Unfortunately homebrew does not have tagged versions for sstp-client, so it is a little more involved - you will need to create a local tap so you can pin the version:

```
$ brew uninstall sstp-client
$ brew tap-new mymac/local
$ brew extract --version 1.0.13 sstp-client mymac/local
$ brew install mymac/local/sstp-client@1.0.13
```

Now it should work as before.

[1] https://sourceforge.net/p/sstp-client/discussion/1499218/thread/d485651bda/?limit=25#268f/038f/4b89/f7be/ffd5

Comment: Thanks for the help...I followed your instructions and got the same error. Do I need to change a path or something in this? Or maybe just uninstall/reinstall again?........
sudo /usr/local/sbin/sstpc --log-stderr --cert-warn --user <user> --password <password> <server> usepeerdns require-mschap-v2 noauth noipdefault defaultroute refuse-eap noccp
.......
brew list confirmed sstp-client@1.0.13

Comment: What does running `/usr/local/sbin/sstpc -v` show?  It should be something like `sstp-client version 1.0.13` if the downgrade worked.

Comment: Yes, when I run that it shows sstp-client version 1.0.13 so it looks like the downgrade worked. But I still get the errors for "Could not complete write of frame" and "Could not forward packet to pppd"

Comment: That specific error can also happen with an incorrect password, did your VPN password change? Is there some way you can confirm that the password is correct - perhaps try the VPN from a Windows client if you have one available?

Comment: I use that username/password regularly on a windows PC so it's definitely correct

Comment: One final thing to try would be if your network admin changed the domain setup, eg if you username was 'sara', it might need to be prefixed with the domain, eg 'somecompany\sara', or maybe the domain changed.  You can find the domain from any windows computer on the network ([How to find my DOMAIN](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_xp-security/how-do-i-find-my-domain-name/0034c26f-157e-e011-9b4b-68b599b31bf5)).